# mat-form-field is not visible and known solutions dont work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have in my Angular project two forms: One login-page and one register-page. The login page is correctly shown:

In the register page are only the first two "mat-form-field"-components shown:

But if I click on the space where the components should be, they are shown:

[After clicking on one free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6h4l.png)

register-page.component.html for the four "mat-form-field"-components:

```
<div class="register-form-user-input"> 
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="register-form-username-field">
                <mat-label lang="en">Username</mat-label> 
                <input type="username" matInput [formControl]="usernameFormControl"     placeholder="Username to show" lang="en">
                <mat-error *ngIf="usernameFormControl.hasError('required')">Username is  <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="register-form-mail-field">
                <mat-label lang="en">Email address</mat-label> 
                <input type="email" matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" placeholder="Ex. name@example.com" lang="en">

                <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">Please enter a valid email address</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">Email is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="register-form-password-field">
                <mat-label lang="en">Password</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="password">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="register-form-confirm-password-field"> 
                <mat-label lang="en">Confirm Password</mat-label>
                <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
                <button tabindex="-1" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
                <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon></button>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

register-page.component.scss:

```
body
{
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-image: url("../../assets/img/login-background.png");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.register-headline
{
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;

    img
    {
        height: 5.5vh;
        margin-left: 2vw;
    } 
}

.register-form-split
{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 4vh;

    hr 
    {
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 100%; 
    }
}

.register-form
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 8vh; 
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-top: 4vh;
    padding-bottom: 1vh; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    display: grid;
    width:fit-content;

    .register-form-information
    {   
        h2
        {
            margin-left: 7.5vw;
            margin-bottom: 4vh;         
            color: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.9); 
            cursor: default;
        }
    }

    .register-form-user-input
    {
        display: grid;
        width:fit-content;

        mat-form-field
        {
            width: 21vw;
            margin-bottom: 1.5vh;
        }
    }

    .register-form-button-area
    {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 6vh;
        width: fit-content;

        .register-form-button-register
        {
            width: 21vw;
            margin-right: 2vw;

            &:hover
            {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        }
    }

    .register-form-hint-area
    {
        width: fit-content;
        margin-top: 2.5vh;
        margin-left: 3.5vw;

        .register-form-hint
        {
            font-size: small;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }

        .register-form-hyperlink
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold; 
            color: rgb(63, 81, 181); 

            &:hover
            {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

I already tried the solution which was mentioned in other blogs:

style.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

html, body 
{ 
    height: 100%;  
}

body 
{   margin: 0; 
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;  
}`

I also use a route for my application. 

app-routing.module.ts:
`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';
import { RegisterPageComponent } from './register-page/register-page.component';

export const routeConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    title: 'xCalendar - Login'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterPageComponent,
    title: 'xCalendar - Register'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Does somedbody has other solutions for my problem?

If you need more information, I can add them. Sorry if there is not enough information for you. I am new at Angular and in stackoverflow.

I already tried to add the "indigo-pink.css"-theme and tried to edit the route-configuration.